# Convert Keras Stateful GRU to TFLite Model?

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, tensorflow-lite

I've got a basic Keras model with a GRU layer where `stateful=True`. I want to convert my model to a TFLite model and make predictions on data one element at a time, i.e a sequence will be fed to the model in batches of size 1. Looking at the TensorFlow Docs, there isn't a way to convert a Stateful GRU to a TFLite Model. However it does say (https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/rnn):

> It is still possible to model a stateful Keras LSTM layer using the underlying stateless Keras LSTM layer and managing the state explicitly in the user program. Such a TensorFlow program can still be converted to TensorFlow Lite using the feature being described here.

I don't what is meant by this. If I set the GRU to not be stateful, how can I prevent its state from being reset after each prediction (batch)? Is there a way to keep the state from resetting?

Comment: So can you convert  the model with either stateful-True or False? Is it possible? Because I do not see a compatibility for GRUs...

Comment: @Farmaker I’m able to convert it provided stateful is set to False. I’m using the experimental TFConverter.

Comment: Please do you have the link of the documentation of the experimental Tfconverter?

Comment: @Farmaker https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/lite/TFLiteConverter I am using this and setting experimental_new_converter to True. I am able to convert and run inference on the model provided my GRU layer is not set to stateful. Is there some sort of way to prevent state resets during inference?

Comment: I am searching but I have not found solution until now